# SSRS report builder 2.0 How to link 2 servers and run in one dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report-builder2.0

I am trying to find a way of linking data from two servers in SSRS report builder 2.0

ultimately using one dataset to query 2 databases in 2 different servers.

The SQL that i have is very basic as shown below and i can run the query easily in SQL management studio.

```
select * from
[server1].[DES].[dbo].[Daily] dr 
LEFT JOIN [server2].[VES].[dbo].[Rou] mr
ON dr.ID = mr.id
```

Also the access i have to the reporting server is read only so i cant really make any administrative changes to the configuration.

I have explored the connection string to create a connection but it only allows me to connect to one server for each dataset. what i am trying to do is use one dataset

Any help will be greatly appreciated as i am a junior in SQL and SSRS

Using SSRS and MS SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if you executing this query from your SSMS it means this other server
>   is a linked server. then it should be no different to execute it from
>   SSRS.
>
> Yes it is right you can only add one server to your data source of
>   your dataset whether its a shared data source or embedded.
>
> But for instance if you have a data source pointing to say Server A
>   when you executing queries which will be pulling data from Server A
>   and also from server B you will Use fully Qualified name for the
>   Objects from server B and two part name from server A.
>
> something like this ...

```
SELECT * 
FROM Schema.Table_Name A INNER JOIN [ServerNameB].DataBase.Schema.TableName B
ON A.ColumnA = B.ColumnA
```

*obviously `ServerB` has to be a `Linked Server`.*

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possible solutions

**Option 1:**
 Creating a stored procedure on server1 (With a query accessing the another server). And call this stored procedure from SSRS (Dataset).

**Option 2:**
Create two dataset with two different connection strings on the RDL (one for Server1 and another for Server2).
Use the "**LookUpDataSet**" function in Report Builder to merge the results using the key fields.

Option 2 is preferable.